# How can I responsively truncate columns in a CSS layout?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
      .postInfo {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 2px;
        width: 128px;
      }
      
      .postThumbnail {
        background-size: 128px;
        height: 72px;
        width: 128px;
      }
      
      .postThumbnail a {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
      }
      
      .postTitle {
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        display: -webkit-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section style="overflow-x: auto;">
      <div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 1 with a lot of text here, that gets limited to two displayed lines">Test 1 with a lot of text here, that gets limited to two displayed lines</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 2">Test 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 3">Test 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 4">Test 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 5">Test 5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

This generates a row of five items, a 128x72px clickable `a` element and a background image above a title. If the row is too wide to display on the viewer's screen, horizontal scrolling becomes an option. I would rather simply truncate the row to the number of full items that can fit on the screen width. How can I accomplish this?

If you go to YouTube and pull up a user's home page, for example [this one](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCivA7_KLKWo43tFcCkFvydw) you'll see that only six videos per section row appear, no matter how wide the screen is. If six don't fit on the screen width only five appear, or four, etc until only one is displayed. This is essentially what I'm trying to accomplish.

I am open to changing anything in this code. It is not a legacy application and can be modified to fit best practices.

Comment: [Media_Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how height of each block, you can use the following:

1. Apply `display: inline-block` on the tiles so the'll wrap nicely
2. Set a `max-height` and `overflow: hidden` on the container to only show **1 row**

Since you already had a static height for the thumbnail, I used a max height of that height + 1 line of text like the example:

<sub>Don't forget to drag your screen to mobile view to see the tiles disappear</sub>

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
      .container {
        height: 98px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .postInfo {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 2px;
        width: 128px;
      }
      
      .postThumbnail {
        background-size: 128px;
        height: 72px;
        width: 128px;
      }
      
      .postThumbnail a {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
      }
      
      .postTitle {
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        display: -webkit-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section style="overflow-x: auto;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 1">Test 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 2">Test 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 3">Test 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 4">Test 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 5">Test 5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Based on the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67663591/how-can-i-responsively-truncate-columns-in-a-css-layout/67679777?noredirect=1#comment119627782_67679777) a snippet with 2 lines;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
      .container {
         height: 113px;
         overflow: hidden;
      }
      .postInfo {
        display: inline-block;
        min-height: 113px;
        vertical-align: top;
        padding: 2px;
        width: 128px;
      }
      
      .postThumbnail {
        background-size: 128px;
        height: 72px;
        width: 128px;
      }
      
      .postThumbnail a {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
      }
      
      .postTitle {
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        display: -webkit-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section style="overflow-x: auto;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 1">Test 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 2">Test 2 With some very large text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 3">Test 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 4">Test 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 5">Test 5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There will be either one or two lines of text underneath the thumbnail. This works fine for when there's only one line.

Comment: Then I'd recommend setting the max-width to the 2-line height. Personally prefer that so they are the same size. You could also allow it to shrink to its 1 or 2 lines but they still wrap the same.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that appears to do what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed your code structure and adapted to flexbox, it should work as you want. If you want to limit width of main div just give `max-width` for `mainDiv`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
      .postInfo {
        display: flex; 
        flex-flow: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content:center;
        padding: 2px;
        width: 200px;
      }
      
      .postThumbnail {
        background-size: 128px;
        height: 72px;
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      .postThumbnail a {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
      }
      
      .postTitle {
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        display: -webkit-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }

      .mainDiv {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section >
      <div class='mainDiv'>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 1">Test 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 2">Test 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 3">Test 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 4">Test 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 5">Test 5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not truncate the columns that don't fit on screen, it simply makes the columns larger or smaller to fill the screen, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I edited my answer and added width: 100px for postInfo and flex-wrap: wrap for mainDiv. Is that the solution you are looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm going to update my question to make clearer what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can just `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: table-cell;` in `.postInfo`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
      .postInfo {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 2px;
        width: 128px;
      }
      
      .postThumbnail {
        background-size: 128px;
        height: 72px;
        width: 128px;
      }
      
      .postThumbnail a {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
      }
      
      .postTitle {
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        display: -webkit-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section style="overflow: hidden;">
      <div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 1">Test 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 2">Test 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 3">Test 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 4">Test 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="postInfo">
          <div class="postThumbnail" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/cJan4sU.png')"><a href="/"></a></div>
          <div class="postTitle" title="Test 5">Test 5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This just makes the item that doesn't fit on the screen move to a new row, it doesn't truncate the row that doesn't fit on screen.

Comment: What do you mean by truncate the row? Cutting of after maximum amount of items is reached (so basically you want to have a row and display as much items as possible ignoring rest of them)? If so, just set **overflow: hidden;** on the div that is wrapping the row (keep **display: inline-block;**)

Comment: I'm changing your answer to reflect the two suggestions from your comment. It doesn't appear to do what I'm looking for.